# How to add more than one resource to this feed structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, feed

I followed how to build a feed in [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec%3athe_status_feed). I have this method in my user model:

```
def feed
  Video.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

and this in my video model:

```
scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

def self.followed_by(user)
  followed_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                       WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
  where("user_id IN (#{followed_ids})", { :user_id => user })
end
```

in order to retrieve all the videos created by the users followed by the current_user.

Then I have this method in my videos_controller:

```
def feed_display
  @videos = current_user.feed.page(params[:page]).per(15)
end
```

and then I render the partial in my `videos/feed_display.html.erb` view:

```
<div id ='video_div'>
    <%= render @videos, :collection => @videos %>
</div>
```

in order to display all the videos that are created by the users the user follows.

Now I want to add another resource to the feed so that it contains both videos and video_votes from the users that the user follows.

I'm thinking of replicating the model scope code that is my video model into my video_vote model and then adding this line:

```
VideoVote.from_users_followed_by(self)
```

to the `feed` method so that it looks like:

```
def feed
  Video.from_users_followed_by(self)
  VideoVote.from_users_followed_by(self)
end
```

My question is how should I modify my `feed_display` method and `feed_display` view so that it not only displays the videos but also the votes?

Comment: is it just me or when i see video as a model i just assume it's you? XD

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your SQL query to include the second model with the UNION statement.

Comment: how would that work? all my SQL query does is select the ids of the users that are followed and my `feed` action takes care of the models...